# Route not accessible from ajax function in a seperate js file in online server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, digital-ocean

I have a laravel project. Each view page has it's on seperate js file. Problem is I am not able to access route functions from ajax post or get call in online server(digital ocean).
Error is:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

The same application is working fine in my local system.
When I add the ajax function inside the design (blade.php) page it's working fine in server. It's not so pleasing to change all my functions inside design.
The server and application was working fine till yesterday.  I made some changes in design and pulled it from bitbucket to server today. After that this error occurred.
Is there anything I have to do in server after pulling from bitbucket. I only pulled the changes made in design.

My route function:

```
Route::prefix('invoice_vno_bind')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', 'InvoiceController@getnextvno')->name('invoice_vno_bind');
    });
```

AJAX function:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "invoice_vno_bind",               
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        $('#txtVNo').val(data);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Error function of ajax is executed when running in online server.

Comment: You should use route method inside ajax function like `url: '{{route('invoice_vno_bind')}}'`

Comment: I am using the same code in my local system and it is working fine..@AmitSenjaliya

Comment: Local and server setup are different so make sure the correct route URL pass inside ajax.

Comment: It was working fine till yesterday. @AmitSenjaliya

Comment: Please try with `route` method on server `url: '{{route('invoice_vno_bind')}}'` because the server may be in strict mode where exact match URL only consider

Comment: Is this the correct format or this :  url: "{{route('invoice_vno_bind')}}" @AmitSenjaliya

Comment: Try this`url: "{{route('invoice_vno_bind')}}"`

Answer (score 0):

First, blade.php in add hidden parameter.

`<input type="hidden" name="ajax_url" id="ajax_url" value="{{ route('invoice_vno_bind') }}">`

And then get **id="ajax_url"** value in js file.

```
var url = $('#ajax_url').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        $('#txtVNo').val(data);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry. the same code is working fine in my local system and also it was fine till yesterday. After using git pull with some design changes, this problem started.

Comment: @FaheemMCFC Have you manually check URL is working? Like hit the URL in browser `http://yourDomainName/invoice_vno_bind`

Comment: yes I checked it and I am getting the data in return successfully @AmitSenjaliya

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the error. It was because of some program lines in
`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/{your file name}`

I commented out the codes below :

```
#    location ~ /.(?!well-known).* {
#       allow all;
#    }
}
```

After commenting it worked fine. I don't know if this will affect any other fields. Till now it's perfectly working.

Thank you all for your suggestions.